# IOS Application Pricing Change

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an IOS app which is free and it has in app purchase options. But I would like to change it a paid app and cancel all in app purchase options. What will happen to existing downloads?

EDIT: Will they need to pay if they update it?

Comment: Keep in mind that all of the people that downloaded your app while it was free and never purchased the in-app upgrade will get your app's full feature set for free after you publish the update and make it a paid app with no in-app purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing.

When you change your terms it doesn't affect existing customers.

(that notwithstanding, they won't be able to purchase more of your (potentially important to them) in-app purchase).

Best of luck.

Comment: When they upgrade new version, they will need to pay wont they?

Comment: EDIT: no, definitely not.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing will happen to the existing customers.  This will only affect customers going forward. However, should they upgrade, they will also be part of the new customer base that includes the paid and in-app options.

Comment: I can force them to upgrade new version. But, will they pay for the app or not?